# ERROR: The application bundle does not contain a valid identifier

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4

I'm getting this error "The application bundle does not contain a valid identifier" after my application successfully compiles.This error prevents my game from launching on the phone or the simulator. I have no idea how to fix this as I was following this tutorial [How To Make A Space Shooter iPhone Game](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3611/how-to-make-a-space-shooter-iphone-game) using Cocos2d.

Answer (score 11):

in my case (working with fastpdfkit, following the 3-minute-tut), the Info.plist was not copied to the bundle. i had to manually (re-)add it in the "Buildphase > Copy Bundle Resources"

Answer (score 8):

The problem that was causing this error message for me was that I had a folder called "Resources":

> This error can also be caused if your project has a sub_directory called 'Resources'; and possibly other special names that I didn't trip over. - [source](http://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/2011/09/26/application-bundle-does-not-contain-valid-identifier#comment-100454)

I also had the `-Info.plist` file missing from the Buildphase (thanks to thumbsup for his [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8490176/377384)).

Answer (score 7):

This could be because the bundle identifier has invalid characters in it or no characters in it. The bundle identifier is found in the Info.plist file.

This is what constitues a valid application bundle identifier:

> The bundle identifier string
>   identifies your application to the
>   system. This string must be a uniform
>   type identifier (UTI) that contains
>   only alphanumeric (A-Z,a-z,0-9),
>   hyphen (-), and period (.) characters.
>   The string should also be in
>   reverse-DNS format. For example, if
>   your company’s domain is Ajax.com and
>   you create an application named Hello,
>   you could assign the string
>   com.Ajax.Hello as your application’s
>   bundle identifier. The bundle
>   identifier is used in validating the
>   application signature.
>   [source (apple developer)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1)

This may also be of use:

> An identifier used by iOS and Mac OS X
>   to recognize any future updates to
>   your app. Your Bundle ID must be
>   registered with Apple and unique to
>   your app. Bundle IDs are app-type
>   specific (either iOS or Mac OS X). The
>   same Bundle ID cannot be used for both
>   iOS and Mac OS X apps.
>   [source](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf)

This is somewhat of a double post - I posted the same answer at [gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12520/error-the-application-bundle-does-not-contain-a-valid-identifier/12523#12523).

Answer (score 6):

delete DerivedData path `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, Xcode removed the Info.plist file from the app target..

1. Select the `Info.plist` in the Project Navigator

[image: Project Navigator]

2. Tick the box for your application

[image: Target Membership]

3. Clean + Build + Run

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. This is how it solved itself:

1. Remove all your extensions from `Build Phases > Target Dependencies` and  `Build Phases > Embed App Extensions` stages.
2. Run `Product > Clean`.
3. Try compiling. For me it worked flawlessly.
4. Add your extensions one by one and do `Product > Clean` + `Product > Run` after adding each of them.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a simple clean option-command-K and shift-option-command-K did the trick.