# The application bundle does not contain a valid identifier IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I will use the camera in my app, and I add Camera Usage Description in Xcode

[image]

but a alert shows the error:

[image]

Someone help me, plus?

UPDATE:

My Bundle Resources:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072755/error-the-application-bundle-does-not-contain-a-valid-identifier

Comment: I try this ways... but doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

RemoveDerived data for your project:
    /Users/{Username}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{AppName}

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed any cocoapods, please deintegrate using- $ pod deintegrate, and uninstall all the cocoapods versions and then delete all of the pod files (pod.lock, pod, xcworkspace) from your project. Now, go to your Xcode project and remove the pod file and framework file from there. Then reinstall your cocoapods version that you need and use your library. It worked for me.