# app installation failed - The application bundle does not contain a valid identifier - Xcode8.2

Tags: ios, xcode

I have got this really strange error where my app works fine on the simulator and can be built but when I try and run it on my device I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Application bundle does not contain a valid identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072755/error-the-application-bundle-does-not-contain-a-valid-identifier).

Comment: this isn't a duplicate - my app works on the simulator

Answer (score 2):

if your bundle id is correct,you can try to delete derivedData folder.
find your path at: Xcode/Preferences/Locations tab
it works for me!

Comment: In my case, the trouble was present on real devices only, I was able to install the application on the xCode simulators. After cleaning the derivedData , the app has been installed successfully on real devices. Thank you for the trick.